# weird Group Policy behaviour

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy

Server: Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Enterprise;
**Installed and tested roles: AD(PDC), DNS, DHCP**

Joined client: Windows XP sp2 professional;
**Installed updates:Group Policy Preference Client Side Extensions for Windows XP;XMLLite for Windows XP**

I created an ou in AD(ou-clients) and put above client into it;then I opened gpo and created a gpo object and linked it to the above ou(ou-clients) path in Group Policy Management(not Enforced);I changed nothing in the other gpo objects(Default Domain Policy, Default Domain Controllers Policy);

The problem is that some settings applies to the client and some not!!!???

for example:
Applied (I saw the result on the client): Do not require ctrl+alt+delete

**Not effective: Prevent changing desktop background** (User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Control Panel\Personalization)

I run `gpupdate /force` on the client with admin credentials; not effective yet;
I restart the client several times; not effective;
I logged in with different user credentials; not effective;

any idea why this setting doesn't apply???

Comment: on the client... logged in as a user that you want this to apply to, run gpresult /r (or just gpresult) and see which policies are being applied

Comment: gun `gpresult /h C:\results.htm` on one of the computers who's policy didn't enforce - that may provide you with some clues

Comment: It seems that everything is fine with gpresult;
my gpo(gpo1) did applied to the computer settings **but in the User Settings section, I can't see my gpo(gpo1) in applied policy section**: it says N/A(although i logged in as one of the users that my gpo can apply to (Authenticated Users))

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the reason that prevent my setting (Prevent changing desktop background) to be applied;

First is that you should add appropriate groups in the **Security Filtering** section; if you'r settings are part of **Computer Configuration** section of the Group Policy Management Editor, then you should add for example `Domain Computers` (or any group that contain you'r desired computers) in the Security Filtering section; And same for the **Users Configuration** section of the Group Policy Management Editor;

Second is that when you are editing a gpo that Security Filtered with domain computers, you should just modify the settings in the **Computer Configuration** section of the Group Policy Management Editor, and when editing a gpo that Security Filtered with domain users, then you should just modify the settings in the **Users Configuration** section of the Group Policy Management Editor.